# Rails username in URL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes

Trying to use a username in my rails routes.

Routes that are working:

```
resources :users, only: [:show, :create, :update, :destroy]
get "/:username" => "users#show", as: :user
get "/:username/account" => "users#account", as: :user_account
get "/:username/interests", to: "users#interests", as: :user_interests
get "/:username/offers" => "users#offers", as: :user_offers
get "/:username/trades" => "users#trades", as: :user_trades
```

but now a route such as this:

```
get "/signup"
```

is being matched to the `/:username` rule

I know I can reorder my routes so that /signup appears before, but this seems a bit hacky.

Are there any ways I can rewrite this? Or is the only method to have a reserved usernames validation?

Thanks

**EDIT**

I ended up adding a validation to the user model with reserved words. Namespacing is a good idea but I don't want to pollute my URLS.

For the record, Twitter namespace non-usernames like this:
twitter.com/i/discover (goes to Twitter discover section)
twitter.com/discover (goes to @discover's profile)

Pinterest reserve names such as 'search' as far as i can tell

I followed Pinterest's approach with code:

validation:

```
validate :reserved_username

private

    def reserved_username
      reserved_usernames = %w[index show create destroy edit update signup interests interest item items search offers offer community about terms privacy admin map authentication]
      errors.add(:reserved_username, "username is reserved for the app") if reserved_usernames.include?(username)
    end
```

Comment: And what if my username IS "signup", or any other real path of your application? To avoid such conflicts, I would highly suggest to nest these paths in their own namespace.

Comment: It's not hacky. That's the way the routes file is supposed to work. You could add a regex condition on the `get "/:username"` line to exclude `/signup`, but that would be completely redundant to having `get "/signup"` come before.

Comment: Agreed; nothing hacky about it: routes is processed in order.

Comment: @christianblais, this sounds interesting. But that would mean I would need to have to have another parameter (thing between /'s) such as /users/adamwaite? correct?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Routes have priority in order of definition, with earlier overriding later. If you want your `/signup` path to work, it needs to be defined before the `/:username` one. This isn't hacky, this is just how it works.

It is possible to exclude certain matches for `:username`, but this slows down your routing if the list gets to be long, or you'll have to re-write it as a regular expression, which is probably the definition of hacky here.

When you're creating root paths for arbitrary usernames, you should think about creating a prefix for all of your other routes so they won't conflict. For example, `/=/signup` or `/-/signup`. You could also use something like `/_signup` if you disallow underscores at the beginning of usernames, or some other way of defining an exclusion you can use to assign all your other routes through.

This way you won't have to worry about checking the user database before introducing a new feature, or creating a long, exhaustive list of invalid names.

Comment: Thanks for this. That's what I feared to be honest. I consider `/-/signup` to be sort of ugly (I'm weird like that) so I think I'm going to have to add a validation to my user model with an array of reserved words.

Comment: It is kind of ugly, but you'll get used to it. You could also push all of your non-user routes through a subdomain, or use a prefix like `.signup` or `~signup` if that looks better.

Comment: Ah, just noticed that Twitter do that so I'm feeling better about it. Pinterest do the reserved names thing. Time to flip a coin I think. Suppose it's only people like us that pay attention to URLs anyway.

Comment: It started with MySpace and everyone's got their own take on how to do it. Twitter's system is just a logical extension of that. If you're concerned about your URLs looking nice, I'd focus on making them understandable more than perfectly pretty. People are conditioned to look for keywords in the URL, nothing more. Syntax is mostly irrelevant.

Comment: Another idea for a character to namespace the username is to use an `@` sign before it, which is what Medium.com does. This became initially popular on Twitter. E.g. `mysite.com/@username`